# Jupyter notebook taking infinite time to train over an SVM kernel

Tags: python, function, kernel, svm

I was trying to write a kernel function manually and do the classification using Support Vector Machine, which was intended to use this manual kernel. I have my dataset as X and labels as y. I simply defined a kernel function, and used it to fit the training dataset. But it is taking infinite time to give any result.

Can you give me any lead?

I also have the following questions:

1. Can it possibly be because I have a sparse dataset? If so, then how can I deal with sparse data?
2. While trying a new kernel, why is it always showing "X.shape[0] should be equal to X.shape[1]" (In my problem, I took the training data to be square matrix so that this error does not appear)? I trid some documentations but I think I am missing something. Can you provide me any article over this?

I tried the following code:

```
# Split the dataset into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
def my_kernel(x,z):
   return sqrt(exp(exp(z)))

clf = SVC(kernel=my_kernel)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
from sklearn import metrics

# Model Accuracy: how often is the classifier correct?
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

This simple code is just running infinintely without any result.
Also, if I am taking X_train such that, number of rows in X_train!=number of columns in X_train, I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 26
     23     return sqrt(exp(exp(z)))
     25 clf = SVC(kernel=my_kernel)
---> 26 clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
     27 y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
     28 from sklearn import metrics

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py:252, in BaseLibSVM.fit(self, X, y,     sample_weight)
    249     print("[LibSVM]", end="")
    251 seed = rnd.randint(np.iinfo("i").max)
--> 252 fit(X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed=seed)
    253 # see comment on the other call to np.iinfo in this file
    255 self.shape_fit_ = X.shape if hasattr(X, "shape") else (n_samples,)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py:315, in BaseLibSVM._dense_fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed)
    312     X = self._compute_kernel(X)
    314     if X.shape[0] != X.shape[1]:
--> 315         raise ValueError("X.shape[0] should be equal to X.shape[1]")
    317 libsvm.set_verbosity_wrap(self.verbose)
    319 # we don't pass **self.get_params() to allow subclasses to
    320 # add other parameters to __init__

ValueError: X.shape[0] should be equal to X.shape[1]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you give more information about how the X_train, y_train looks like? Maybe some toy example so we can provide more detailed help? :)

Comment: X_train is a list containing 686 arrays and each array contains 686 elements. y_train is of length 686 containing binary labels(1 and -1)

Answer (score 1):

The kernel function is given two data matrices: `n_samples_1 x n_features` and `n_samples_2 x n_features` (at train time I think they're the same). Your function should return a matrix of size `n_samples_1 x n_samples_2`. In other words, your kernel function needs to take each sample in matrix 1, and compute the kernel between that sample and each sample in matrix 2. Then you take the next sample in matrix 1, and compute the kernel with every sample in matrix 2. You end up with a matrix of size `n_samples_1 x n_samples_2`, where each entry is the value of the kernel function between two samples.

Your current kernel function returns a matrix of size `n_samples_2 x n_features`. If you instead run your kernel on the dot product of your features: `kernel_ij = sqrt(exp(exp( feat0_i*feat0_j + feat1_i*feat1_j + ... ))`, it will give you a result matrix that has the right dimensions `n_samples_1 x n_sampels_2`:

```py
def my_kernel(X, Y):
    return np.sqrt(np.exp(np.exp(X @ Y.T)))
```

The code example below does this and plots the decision boundary.

[image]

Viewed in 3D:

[image]

```py
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

#Synthetic data
n_pts = 200
y = np.hstack([np.ones(n_pts // 2), np.zeros(n_pts // 2)])
X = np.hstack([np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_pts)).reshape(-1, 1),
               np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_pts)).reshape(-1, 1)]) +\
                   np.random.randn(n_pts, 2) / 10

#Define a kernel and fit classifier
def my_kernel(X, Y):
    return np.sqrt(np.exp(np.exp(X @ Y.T)))

clf = SVC(kernel=my_kernel)
clf.fit(X, y)

print('Classifier train score is:', clf.score(X, y))

#
#Plots
#Show the original data, and the decision boundaries
#
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, zorder=2, cmap='bwr', marker='s', s=40)
ax.set_xlabel('feature 0')
ax.set_ylabel('feature 1')

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(X[:, 0].min(), X[:, 0].max()),
    np.linspace(X[:, 1].min(), X[:, 1].max())
)
feat_space = np.stack([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()], axis=1)

predictions = clf.predict(feat_space).reshape(xx.shape)
decision_vals = clf.decision_function(feat_space).reshape(xx.shape)

#Floodfill with predicted class
cont_fill = ax.contourf(xx, yy, predictions, alpha=0.3, cmap='bwr')

#Overlay lightsource shading - lighsource help brings out the topography
# shaded = matplotlib.colors.LightSource().shade_rgb(matplotlib.cm.bwr(predictions),
#                                                    decision_vals,
#                                                    vert_exag=3,
#                                                    fraction=1)
# ax.imshow(shaded, alpha=0.5, extent=ax.axes.axis())

#Contours highlighting the decision terrain
cont_lines = ax.contour(xx, yy, decision_vals, levels=10, cmap='cool', alpha=0.8)
ax.clabel(cont_lines, inline=True, fontsize=10, colors='k')

ax.set_title('Samples (squares) overlaid onto region\n'
             'predictions (background), with decision\nfunction contours')
```

For the 3D plot:

```py
#3D
decision_vals_at_samples = clf.decision_function(X)

ax3d = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5)).add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax3d.view_init(elev=15, azim=120, roll=0)
ax3d.scatter3D(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], decision_vals_at_samples, c=y, cmap='bwr', alpha=0.7)
surf = ax3d.plot_surface(xx, yy, decision_vals,
                         linewidth=0.1, rcount=30, ccount=30,
                         facecolors=matplotlib.cm.bwr(decision_vals), facecolor=[0,0,0,0])
# ax3d.plot_wireframe(xx, yy, decision_vals, cmap='bwr', linewidth=0.2)
ax3d.set_xlabel('feature 0')
ax3d.set_ylabel('feature 1')
ax3d.set_zlabel('decision function')
ax3d.set_title('Samples overlaid onto decision function (mesh)\n'
               'Mesh coloured by class prediction')
```

---

Regarding your question in the comments about operating on a single variable, you can do it as follows.

```py
def my_kernel_absX(X, Y):
    select_feature = 0 #apply function to the first feature
    kernel_x = np.abs(X[:, 0]).reshape(-1, 1)
    kernel_rpt_for_y = np.tile(kernel_x, [1, len(Y)])
    return kernel_rpt_for_y

def my_kernel_absY(X, Y):
    select_feature = 0 #apply function to the first feature
    kernel_y = np.abs(Y[:, select_feature]).reshape(1, -1)
    kernel_rpt_for_x = np.tile(kernel_y, [len(X), 1])
    return kernel_rpt_for_x
```

A kernel function is usually defined for a pair of variables, so I don't think the functions above would count as kernel functions.

Comment: Updated with 3D view of the classifier's `decision_function()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to use "np.sqrt(np.exp(np.exp(X @ Y.T))) " as kernel function. but it still gives the error "ValueError: The dual coefficients or intercepts are not finite. The input data may contain large values and need to bepreprocessed.". I have another question following your answer, how do we put the kernel function if we have apply operator on a single variable? e.g., if we want to use |y|?

Comment: For SVMs especially, it helps if you scale the data before feeding it in. You can scale the data using `X_scaled = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)`. Use the scaled features rather than the original ones. That will help the SVC converge, and might also solve the error you're seeing (if the error persists see if removing one of the `np.exp()` helps, as exponentiation quickly produces huge numbers).

Comment: Please see my updated answer regarding your second question about |y|.